# Why sort([1,2,3]){true} doesn't work in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know this example is entirely useless and contrived, but I'm trying to better wrap my head around how values get handled in Swift and I don't understand why the following code returns an error.

```
var notSorted = sort([1,2,3,4]){true}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of `sort` has type `(T, T) -> Bool`, but you are supplying a `() -> Bool`, namely a closure with no parameters that returns `true`.

Of course the two types don't match and you rightfully get a compile-time error.

Something like this will work:

```
var notSorted = sort([1,2,3,4]){_ in true}
```

---

By the way, that closure has the effect of reversing the array. If you want to perform a nop, you have to put `false`.

Comment: Ah-ha!  I understand, I was just thinking in terms of the return values, and didn't realize the full closure being passed is type safe.  Thank you!

Comment: I guess something changed since Jun 4. The current beta gives an error on this statement. The error marker points to the left bracket and says "'inout C does not have a member named 'Element'". I don't know what that means.

Comment: @RobertL try renaming `sort` in `sorted`